# filter data frame with two conditions columns?

Tags: r, subset

I have data set like this,

```
S.No.   Counts  No.rep  Fram
1   3   4   UNC84A
2   10  4   UNC84A
3   7   4   UNC84A
4   10.3    4   UNC84A
5   7   1   NTUD19
6   181 3   ALR6IP4
7   7   3   ALR6IP4
8   21  3   ALR6IP4
```

I would like to filter "if No.rep>=3" then select column which has "Counts>= 10". Also, when No.rep < 3, I would required to have columns with Counts < 10 as well.

This is my required output

```
S.No.   Counts  No.rep  Fram
2   10  4   UNC84A
4   10.3    4   UNC84A
5   7   1   NTUD19
6   181 3   ALR6IP4
8   21  3   ALR6IP4
```

Comment: `5 7 1 NTUD19` Breaks your rules.

Comment: @ Badger you are right I would like to have this coulumn "5 7 1 NTUD19" also in my output.

Comment: Very confusing, based on your comment below and the question above, you want Reps both `>` and `<` `3` and Counts both `>` and `<` `10`, resulting in the entire dataset. Could you refine your question to reflect the output you seek?

Comment: @ Badger I have edited the question, is it making sense to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df[df["No.rep"] >= 3 & df["Counts"] >= 10,]
S.No. Counts No.rep    Fram
    2   10.0      4  UNC84A
    4   10.3      4  UNC84A
    6  181.0      3 ALR6IP4
    8   21.0      3 ALR6IP4
```

EDIT:

Do you want an OR condition like so:

`df[(df["No.rep"] >= 3 & df["Counts"] >= 10) | (df["No.rep"] < 3 & df["Counts"] < 10),]`

```
  S.No. Counts No.rep    Fram
      2   10.0      4  UNC84A
      4   10.3      4  UNC84A
      5    7.0      1  NTUD19
      6  181.0      3 ALR6IP4
      8   21.0      3 ALR6IP4
```

Comment: Jayception going on here. I agree with you Jay 2.0, but Jay 1.0's desired output breaks the rule they have set. I assume typo on their part and that you are correct.

Comment: Yes, I also assumed it was an error in their expected output.  If not they best revise their post.

Comment: @ Jay, thanks very much, I am also looking to have if "No.rep" <3, I would like to have columns with Counts of <10. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: This is not very clear.  I've edited the above guessing that you want an OR condition.